# libc stat function and LuaJIT

Tags: c, lua, luajit

I've been poking all day with one misterious misbehaviour of LuaJIT. The `libc` `stat` function returns wrong value in its `stat` buffer.

The LuaJIT script:

```
-- definitions for sys/types.h
 typedef uint32_t      mode_t;
 typedef uint64_t      dev_t;
 typedef uint64_t      ino_t;
 typedef unsigned int  nlink_t;
 typedef int           pid_t;
 typedef unsigned int  id_t;
 typedef unsigned int  uid_t;
 typedef unsigned int  gid_t;
 typedef int64_t       off_t;
 typedef long          blksize_t;
 typedef int64_t       blkcnt_t;
 typedef uint64_t      fsblkcnt_t;
 typedef uint64_t      fsfilcnt_t;

-- for sys/stat.h
  struct stat {
   dev_t      st_dev;         /* Device */
   ino_t      st_ino; /* File serial number. */
   nlink_t    st_nlink;     /* Link count.  */
   mode_t     st_mode; /* File mode.  */
   uid_t      st_uid; /* User ID of the file's owner. */
   gid_t      st_gid; /* Group ID of the file's group.*/
   int        __pad0;
   dev_t      st_rdev; /* Device number, if device.  */
   off_t      st_size;     /* Size of file, in bytes.  */
   blksize_t  st_blksize; /* Optimal block size for I/O.  */
   blkcnt_t   st_blocks; /* Number 512-byte blocks allocated. */
   /* __USE_XOPEN2K8 */
   struct timespec st_atim; /* Time of last access.  */
   struct timespec st_mtim; /* Time of last modification.  */
   struct timespec st_ctim; /* Time of last status change.  */
   long   __unused[3];
  };
  /* luajit calls this */
  int __xstat(int ver, const char *path, struct stat *buf); 

-- lua stat function part
stat = function(path, buf) return ffi.C.__xstat(_STAT_VER, path, buf) end;
```

The above were taken from my system C header files. Now the LuaJIT call is:

```
local buf = ffi.new("struct stat[1]")
local res = stat('main.c', buf)
ffi.cdef [[
 int printf(const char *fmt, ...);
]]
ffi.C.printf("size: %lu, ino: %lu, mode: %d\n", buf[0].st_size, buf[0].st_ino, buf[0].st_mode);
```

The `struct stat[1]` in `ffi.new` was kindly suggested by a luajit mail list.

***Update***

***The idea is to call linux __xtat. Declaration added.***

The `__xstat` aproach were taken from https://github.com/Wiladams/LJIT2libc. Othervise it is too much definitions in the `C` headers for me.

The output goes normal, until the `st_mode` field. The field is zero. I did a test with a `C` language and all went good. So the problem is in that LuaJIT `stat` gives me wrong results. Please advise what to do. Have put all day on that thingy.

Comment: I think you should open a ticket on the LuaJIT issue tracker (on Github https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT).

Comment: Please show how did you declare `stat` function.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I missed that. made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few typos in my `ffi.cdef` type declarations. The problem is solved now, with the help of a users of `luajit` mail list. To make a quick resume:

1. Take an output of `clang -E <some_c_file>.c` command that is invoked on a `C` source file, that contains `#include <sys/stat.h>`.
2. Make a proper `struct stat` definition.
3. My system `stat` function has a way too many levels of macro garbage. In the end, the `stat` function invokes `__xstat`. The only sane way for me to call a `stat` function is to make a `syscall`.
4. Have in mind that `Lua` `print` function does not know about `cdata` type. And `printf` does not know about `Lua` types. But `luajit` have a nice and easy explanation about how to convert common data types back and forth.